# How to re-create jQuery data-table on ajax response?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am creating a jQuery data-table based on some search criteria using ajax call & response. 
I am able to create the table. But when I try to search again, I am getting the below error.

> DataTables warning: table id=sendBulkEmailTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

I guess I cannot re-create the data table again. Can somebody provide a solution to my problem, how can I refresh the data of my table on next search.

jQuery ajax call I wrote is:

```
     $("#tableId").dataTable({
        "data": res.ajaxResult.data,
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "data1" },
                    { "data": "data2" },
                    { "data": "data3" },
                    { "data": "data4" },
                    { "data": "data5" }
                 ]
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation linked to in the error message, you can either destroy the existing data table with the `destroy: true` option , or implement an AJAX reload mechanism with ajax.reload()

http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy

http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()